# Defect - The link "delete" does not work

Tags: bug, deletion, questions

There is an annoying defect in the site https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com

I am on the site https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com on an iPhone on iOS 9.0.2.

On a question by me, the link "delete" does not work.

Later, on my Mac, on Firefox, I can delete my question.

Can someone correct that defect please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

I'll repeat my answer from your previous bug report:

**You are using an [unsupported browser](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161/295232)**. iOS 9 is five years old now, and its Safari browser doesn't support some of the JavaScript that link is using (at least, that's my assumption). I'm sorry, but it's unlikely the development team will fix that bug. It's hard keeping a site working on so many different browsers, that energy is better spent elsewhere.